# Proof of Positivity for Solutions in Ordinary Differential Equations (ODEs)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, dynamical-systems, initial-value-problems

Let $x(t)$ be the solution of the initial value problem:
$$
\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t)); \; \; x(0) = x_0
$$

I have made the following asumption during my work:

If $x_0 \geq 0$, and $f(0) \geq 0$, then $x(t) \geq 0$ for $t \geq 0$.

It intuitivelly makes sense: starting with x positive, it might decrease until $x=0$. But as soon as it reaches that point, $\dot{x} = f(0) \geq 0$, so it either "grows back up" or just stay at $0$.

I feel like there should be a simple proof for this, but I cannot find one.

Also, if it not true, what additional conditions should I add? Maybe  Lipschitz continuity of $f$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\dot{x} = f >0\implies x(t)$ is increasing $\implies  x(t) \ge x(0) = x_0 \ge 0$

Comment: What if $f \geq 0$? @NN2

Comment: @HyperbolicPDEfriend it was a typo, it should be $\dot{x}=f \ge 0\implies x(t) $ is not decreasing, then $x(t) \ge x(0)$…

Comment: I'm afraid that this is generally untrue, at least if only $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untrue if $f$ is not locally Lipschitz-continuous. Take e.g. $f(x) = 0$ for $x \geq 0$ and $f(x) = -\sqrt{-x}$ for $x \leq 0$. Then
$$
x(t) = 
\begin{cases}
    0 & t \leq 0 \\
    -\tfrac{1}{4}t^2 & t > 0
\end{cases}
$$
is a solution to $x' = f(x)$, $x(0)= 0$. Check that this contradicts your hypothesis.

If you assume however that $f$ is locally Lipschtz, then your claim is true. First note, that solutions to $x' = f(x)$, $x(0) = x_0$ are then **unique**!
Then let $y$ be the solution to the IVP $y' = f(y) - f(0)$, $y(0) = x_0$. Note that $0$ is a constant solution to $v' = f(v)-f(0)$, so due to uniqueness, either $y =0$ (if $x_0=0$) or $y>0$ if $x_0>0$ (the constant solution $0$ can't be intersected!).

Now, since $x' = f(x) \geq f(x) - f(0)$ (remember $f(0) \geq 0$) we can use the ODE comparison principle (Teschl, ordinary differential equations p.24, Lemma 1.2) to conclude that $x \geq y \geq 0$ for $t \geq 0$.
Note very carefully that Teschl indeed requires uniqueness to the ODE (see text after (1.61)) which is not the case in my above example.

I guess that this result is hard to find, since many consider this result intuitive, but "annoying to prove rigorously".